# How to update cell of the table by click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table and want to insert some value(x) in the cell by click. please someone help how to implement this in Angular?

Here is my html:

```
<table class="board">
    <h1>Table</h1>
    <input type="number" ng-model="val">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.foo(val)">PRESS</button>

    <tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.arr">
        <td ng-repeat="td in ctrl.arr" ng-click="ctrl.getIndex($parent.$index, $index)" class="{{ctrl.class}}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

A here is the code:

```
function GameOfLifeCntl() {

    this.foo = function(size) {

        this.arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this.arr.push(i);
        }
    }
    this.getIndex = function(parent, index) {
        console.log(parent, index);
    }
}
```

Here is the link  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufaj6kcm/5/)

Comment: I can't see the variable `ctrl` in your controller. Can you post it? And what value do you want to alter? And why do you have two nested ng-repeat's?

Comment: What's the problem here? Your code works fine so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ufaj6kcm/1/ - I just added a binding to `{{td}}` so you can see the table cells being printed

Comment: you are calling ctrl.getIndex from html side but in script you are using getIndex . so i thik it will not print console .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ufaj6kcm/1/

no, I need to insert the value by click. All cells are empty, but when I click that cell gets the value, for example 'X'

Comment: 23tux,   ctrl it's <div  ng-controller="GameOfLifeCntl as ctrl">

Comment: RGraham,   like this http://jsfiddle.net/ufaj6kcm/2/    but it shouldn't put it everywhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the $event variable in getIndex function like this

```
<td ng-repeat="td in ctrl.arr" ng-click="ctrl.getIndex($event, $parent.$index, $index)" class="{{ctrl.class}}"></td>
```

and then in getIndex function you can put text in the target clicked

```
ctrl.getIndex = function(e, i, j) { e.currentTarget.text(i + ',' + j)}
```

something like this

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one.

```
    `http://jsfiddle.net/ufaj6kcm/11/`
```

First you need to construct two dimensional array of object.
The rest data binding is automatically handled by AngularJS  **two - way data binding** .

I hope this will help you.

Thanks.